# Browserify External Requires with Grunt-Browserify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify, commonjs

The Browserify docs section on [external requires](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires) shows how to make a module within a bundle available to the global environment:

```
browserify -r through -r duplexer -r ./my-file.js:my-module > bundle.js
```

But I'm having trouble configuring this to work with Grunt-Browserify.

The `-r` flag seems to correspond to the `require` option in Grunt-Browserify, but the [docs description for this option](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify#require) doesn't make any mention of external requires or exporting a `require()` function.

In my Gruntfile, I've tried setting the `require` option to the module I need to expose (which is already in the bundle, by the way):

```
options: {
  require: ['./dev/js/foomod.js'],
}
```

And then in my page script, I try to `require()` the module as shown in the docs:

```
<script>
  var Foomod = require('./foomod.js');
  Foomod.init({foo: 'bar'});
</script>
```

But that logs the error `require is not defined`.

My goal is to call the module's `init()` method as shown so that I can pass in runtime data without putting it in a `window` global.

Answer (score 0):

Using browserify version 5.11.1 and grunt-browserify version 3.0.1, I have managed to get similar setup to work:

```
options:{
  preBundleCB: function (b) {
    b.require("./dev/js/foomod.js",{expose: 'foomod'});
  }
}
```

Comment: So once you set this up on options under browserify task, require function was defined globally? I just did what you mentioned, and I'm still having the "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" error when trying to require the files from my index page

Comment: Did you use require("foomod")?

Comment: I have an 'app.js' which is the bundle, inside of it there is an 'initialize.coffee' - I'm already using coffeeify for the transform - and I'm using require('initialize') to no effect, since 'require' seems to be still undefined